# Water Gas Shift Reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

Considering the [water-gas shift reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water-gas_shift_reaction)

$$\ce{CO(g) + H2O(g) <=> CO2(g) + H2(g)},$$

I would like to understand how evolves $K^\circ$ the equilibrium constant of this reaction when I add water with a fixed temperature (and pression).

I know that

$$K^\circ = \frac{x(\ce{CO2})\cdot x(\ce{H2})}{x(\ce{CO})\cdot x(\ce{H2O})}.$$

I am wondering how is the equilibrium affected when we add some water.

Comment: If you add water without changing the temperature and the pressure, the equilibrium constant $K°$  is not modified. The only effect would be that the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2}$ goes up.

Comment: Thank you Maurice, how can we prove that?

Comment: @Poutnik that's right, I was rather unclear. I am asking how does change the latter compared to the former.

Comment: @Poutnik I get that. If I am posting this question it is because I don't know where precisely to search this information and I was looking for someone to get me on the right path. I don't need people to do my own work, but I would love some help for me to see it through.

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you. I must have made a confusion. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: No bothering, you are welcome. This site prefers teaching fishing instead of giving fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may confuse [equilibrium constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_constant) and [reaction quotient.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_quotient)

> In chemical thermodynamics, the reaction quotient is a quantity that provides a measurement of the relative quantities of products and reactants present in a reaction mixture for a reaction with well-defined overall stoichiometry, at a particular point in time. Mathematically, it is defined as the ratio of the activities of the product species over those of the reactant species involved in the chemical reaction, taking stoichiometric coefficients of the reaction into account as exponents of the concentrations. In equilibrium, the reaction quotient is constant over time and is equal to the equilibrium constant.

By adding water, you change the reaction quotient, but not the equilibrium constant.

If you add some reagens to a systém in equilibrium, you shift the quotient value away from the equilibrium constant. The reaction is then ongoing in the direction which causes convergence of the reaction quotient toward the equilibrium constant.

The equilibrium constant depends only on temperature.